# Listing company award on LinkedIn and/or resume

Tags: resume, linkedin

I recently received an award at work during the yearly awards ceremony. Those awards are celebrating 10 employees on 5 different categories (2 employees each) out of 800 or so employees and each award is the result of peer voting (i.e. anybody votes, not just managers). The award I have received is for "Contribution and support", which essentially means being instrumental to the success of a significant project and/or being particularly supportive of your colleagues / being a team player.

I was originally thinking of adding this to my "Honors and awards" section in LinkedIn, which is quite frankly thin at the moment, and mentioning it under my current work on my resume when I will update it.

It crossed my mind that this could be viewed more as filler than anything and could make me seem a bit try-hard. Am I downplaying my award or is it really worth it putting on my LinkedIn / social media.

Note: I do understand this could be perceived as a question with a subjective answer. More generally, my question is whether a company award voted by peers during a yearly ceremony is resume-material.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see what it could hurt.  A peer award is nothing to take lightly - it shows that you are a team player who is well respected by others in the company.  Listing it on LinkedIn may give you the opportunity to showcase your collaboration skills in an interview if the reviewers scan through your profile and notice it.

If you decide to post it, make sure to describe it is you did here - a result of peer voting.  If you can call out the exact reason for the award, so much the better.

Answer (score 1):

I would list the award, because it shows that you are an instrumental team player. The award is directly relevant to most roles, so it would be a good addition to your LinkedIn.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question are going to be very subjective.  In addition to that, potential employers will have differing views.  At best, listing the award can be viewed as a positive, at worst it will be taken with a grain of salt.  If a potential employer sees an award like "Employee of the Year" from a company like Microsoft, it will hold more credibility than an award from an unknown company.